# 2D pixel-perfect collision detection with opengl

Tags: opengl, 2d, sprite, collision-detection

I'm writing a 2D, sprite-based game and I'm having a hard time with making collision detection. First of all, I am well aware of other methods and in fact I'm using Box2D's quadtree queries to filter out non-overlapping sprites. So pixel-perfect detection would be used only on sprites that were found to overlap and would be used only a few times per frame. The sprites are rotating but not scaling.

The problem is I need it done with pixels because the sprites can change over time and making and using e.g. Box2D's geometric shapes for approximate the bitmap will get really complicated.

I did some research and found out these methods are possible in OpenGL in order to check if any pixels with non-zero alpha channel overlap:

1) **Rendering sprites to a texture/buffer with e.g. 50% alpha and proper blending function, copying the result to RAM and checking if there's any pixel with alpha greater with e.g. 80%.**

This method is simple but as I checked copying back is extremely slow.

2) **Using OpenGL's occlusion query.**

From what I found out on the net occlusion queries can be tricky (plus sometimes you need to wait until the next frame to get the result) and buggy on some graphic cards. The fact such queries don't produce results immediately is a deal breaker because of how the game is designed to work.

3) **Shaders and atomic counters.**

I'm not sure if it would work but it seems that using a fragment shader when rendering a second sprite that would increase an atomic counter each time it overwrites something and then checking the counter's value on the CPU side could be a solution. The only problem is that atomic counters are pretty new and 2,3-years old machines may not support them.

Is there something I missed? Or should I just forgot about using GPU and write my own renderer just for collision detection on CPU?

Comment: You could go with atomic counters, and use a simpler approximate method as a fallback for older hardware. E.g. approximate the shape of the sprites with one or more discs, precomputed if that's possible. I don't know if that makes sense for your sprites. Multiple implementations will be harder to maintain though.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic Counters is an appropriate way to do this on the GPU. Since you're going to be checking many many pixels, you might as well do this in parallel. The big performance question here is asynchronously reading it back, but this depends on how you make your engine of course.

With OpenGL 4.2 you can use atomic counters. Check if your graphics card supports this, it's quite possible it does, you should check this.